# Ask Mathematica if there exists a value that satisfies conditions

Tags: boolean-computation, inequalities

I would like to build a function that returns true if there exists even one value of xg1 such that having as inputs Mtot, PL, xg2, mac, xga, and defining

```
xgtot = (xg1 PL + xg2 Mtot)/(Mtot + PL);
stab = (xga - xgtot)/mac;
```

the following conditions are satisfied:

```
0.1<stab<0.4
xgtot<0.2;
```

I would like such a function to return only True or False.

I tried using AnyTrue, but it doesn't seam to work as I wanted:

```
    tests = {0.1<#1 < 0.4 &, #2 < 0.2 &};
AnyTrue[{stab, xg1} , TrueQ[tests] ]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you could write a function that uses FindInstance or Reduce, then if an answer is returned by those functions, it in turn returns True, otherwise False.

Comment: It seams to work out with FindInstance. How may I make it return True or False?

Comment: To make it return True or False, just test whether its output is `{}` (False) or something else (True).  The following would work: `FindInstance[(*tests*), {(*variables*)}] =!= {}`  You may also want to know that `=!=` is a short for `UnsameQ`.

Comment: And if you reply to a comment, you should add a @MarcoB somewhere in your comment to send him a 'notification'.  Otherwise he won't know you replied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mainly just to see how `Reduce@Exists[..]` stacks up against `FindInstance[]`.  I suspect the heuristics of `FindInstance` will often beat symbolic reduction, but apparently not in this case.

```
Clear[xg1, Mtot, PL, xg2, mac, xga, stab, xgtot];
xgtot = -(xg1 PL + xg2 Mtot)/(Mtot + PL);
stab = (xga - xgtot)/mac;
Reduce[
  Exists[{xg1, Mtot, PL, xg2, mac, xga}, 
   0.1 < stab < 0.4 && xgtot < 0.2]
  ] // RepeatedTiming
FindInstance[0.1 < stab < 0.4 && xgtot < 0.2,
   {xg1, Mtot, PL, xg2, mac, xga}] =!= {} // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.0081, True}
  {0.0087, True}
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Following MarcoB's comments and QuantumDot's suggestion, a solution could be to simply use FindInstance:

```
    FindInstance[(xga - (xg1 PL + xg2 Mtot)/(Mtot + PL))/mac < 0.4 && 
   xg1 > 0.3 && 0.1 < stab < 0.4, {xg1}] =!= {}
```

Thank you very much!